# jQuery - Go through each div and if element doesn't exists hide other element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with jQuery. I tried to make script that would do this: "Go through each div with identical class `.photo` and if element doesn't exists in this div `.caption h1` hide `.photo .date p`".

Seems like an easy thing to do, but I tried everything and can't get this to work. Below is my script that doesn't work.

```
$('.photo').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($('.photo .caption h1').length === 0) {
        $('.photo .date p').hide();
    }
});
```

Did I miss something or is this whole script wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.photo').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).find('.caption h1').length === 0) {
        $(el).find('.date p').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Finally! It took me some time, but FINALLY I figured it out. I changed `.length > 0` to `.length === 0` and it works. You propably missunderstood me :P Thanks a lot man, if been strugling with this for couple days :O :D THANKS A LOT MAN!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.photo').each(function(i, obj) {
 if($(obj).find(".caption h1").length != 0){
   $(obj).find(".date p").hide();
 }
}):
```